# Correct texture colors on iOS using OpenGL ES 2.0 vbos/varrays but wrong colors on Windows and MAC

Tags: ios, macos, colors, cross-platform, opengl-es-2.0

I have following problem:

I have correct texture colors on iOS using OpenGL ES 2.0 vbos or vertex arrays, but wrong colors on Windows and MAC. Application code is the same just some differences in the rendering system. (Also nearly the same shaders for all systems). (Normal textures work perfectly well on all systems - just a quad with a texture on it drawn with an vertex array - glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, primitiveCount*3, indexSize, indexList) )

I uploaded a picture to show what's happening at all!

[image: wrong colors on windows and mac for the sourrounding particles (correct one on iOS - blue)]

First I thought it may be a Problem with the vertex shader but I guess not. But maybe it is, so I'll post it:

```
            GLbyte vertexShaderFile[] = 
        "attribute vec4 inVertexPosition;                       \n"
        "attribute vec4 inVertexColor;                          \n"
        "attribute vec4 inTexCoord0;                            \n"
        "uniform mat4 uOrthoMatrix;                         \n"
        "varying vec4 varVertexColor;                           \n"
        "varying vec4 varTexCoord;                          \n"
        "                                       \n"
        "void main(void)                                \n"
        "{                                      \n"
        "   gl_Position    = uOrthoMatrix * inVertexPosition;           \n"
        "   varVertexColor = inVertexColor.bgra;                    \n"
        "   varTexCoord    = inTexCoord0;                       \n"
        "}                                      \n";



        GLbyte fragmentShaderFile[] = 
#if defined(FHZ_IOS) || defined(FHZ_WIN)
        "precision mediump float;                           \n"
#endif // FHZ_IOS
        "uniform bool uUseTexture;                          \n"
        "uniform sampler2D uTextureUnit;                        \n"
        "uniform bool uAlphaTest;                           \n"
        "uniform float uAlphaValue;                         \n"
        "varying vec4 varVertexColor;                           \n"
        "varying vec4 varTexCoord;                          \n"
        "                                       \n"
        "void main(void)                                \n"
        "{                                      \n"
        "   vec4 color = varVertexColor;                        \n" 
        "   vec4 texel = texture2D(uTextureUnit, varTexCoord.xy);           \n"
        "   if(uUseTexture)                             \n"
        "   {                                   \n"
        "       color *= texel.bgra;                        \n"
        "   }                                   \n"
        "                                       \n"
        "   if(uAlphaTest && !(color.a > uAlphaValue))              \n"
        "       discard;                            \n"
        "                                       \n"
        "   gl_FragColor = color;                           \n"
        "}                  

                \n";
```

When I exchange vec4 color = varVertexColor; with a fix color vector of vec4(1,1,1,1); The colored particles have the same color as the normal texture on ALL platforms, but I really don't
understand why this makes any difference. So that lead me to the opinion it may be a wrong initialisation of open gl es 2.0 on windows and mac - because I have to do it on my own. On iOS it's already "done" by the underlaying system.

I hope someone can help me with this issue :)

Comment: How is the inVertexColor being passed to your application? Are you using OpenGL ES 2.0 on windows/mac or a normal OpenGL implementation?

Comment: I'm using normal OpenGL ES 2.0 on windows and mac too. The colors are passed to the application via  glVertexAttribPointer( EVA_COLOR, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, true, sizeof( S3DVertex ), &( static_cast<const S3DVertex*>( vertices ) )[0].Color ); whereas the struct S3DVertex has the color vector which stores (a,r,g,b) with range [0-255]

Comment: let's try to modify the fragment shader another way: vec4 color = vec4(.0, .0, 1.0, 1.0)/*varVertexColor*/; to see if the textures do get blue on all the platforms (if they do, that means the color attribute is not passed correctly)